# Is there any conlang where syllables are inverse to word frequency?

Tags: phonology

Is there any conlang where the more common words are shorter, and the more syllables a word has, the rarer (in terms of occurrence) it is?

Comment: Frankly, I'd be surprised if there were languages where this wasn't case. Shorter words are easier to say and natlangs naturally make "filler words" such as pronouns, prepositions, conjunctions and 'particles' - which basically means "any filler word that doesn't fit into one of the above categories" - shorter than the average word. And conlangers have noticed this, even if subconsciously, and make their words accordingly. Even Toki Pona does this, and it's words are two syllables max!

Answer (score 1):

Words tend to get trimmed down over time, with more commonly used words being more prone to this. Thus, its natural for common words to be shorter than less rarely used ones. I've seen conlangs get criticized for not adhering to this rule (such as having the word for 'new' be three syllables in length, in a conlang with a VERY liberal phonotactics that should allow an abnormally wide variety of syllables). Of course, not everyone adheres to it, but some try to.

Answer (score 0):

I have no data but I guess naturalistic conlangs like Interlingua and even the more schematic Esperanto have this property.